# Timers, Files and race conditions?

Tags: c#, timer, streamwriter

Hello and thanks for your help.
This time I am having a curious problem with a program (C#) I am writing and would like to hear your advice. 
I am writing a normal program (not multithreaded) but then added a timer (System.Timers.Timer)

Also I am using a StreamWriter to write on a file. I open this like this

```
StreamWriter logStream=new StreamWriter(filename, true);
```

meaning that if the file exists, it appends , if not it creates.

Later I write in the file like this

```
logStream.WriteLine(message);
```

However, I write to the stream from  *both* the main function and from the function that is called by the timer.

**the problem symptoms**

My program is throwing an error sometimes when I flush or write the stream saying that "Can not access a closed file" and other times "Can not access a closed TextWriter... (What is a "TextWriter"?)

However curiously, the file keeps being written without problem. (Even the "can not access a closed file" message is written in the supposed closed file)

I am not familiar with the inner workings of a Timer. (I suppose it runs a separate thread?)

My question is

**Is it possible to use a StreamWriter from several threads? (in this case the main one and the Timer one)
Is it possible that there is happening a race condition or some problem like that?**

---

One more thing: I made a logic mistake and close and reopen the file every time I want to write on it. Yes, it is a mistake and I should correct it. But maybe if I correct this the error I described above will disappear masking a more serious flaw.

My suspicions is that since I am closing and opening the file *every*  time I write on it, maybe the both threads try to access them on a wrong time

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: To one of your questions: A StreamWriter is a specific TextWriter.

Comment: Are you trying to create a logging implementation? Why don't you use .NET's built-in diagnostics API or a logging library like log4net? Logging libraries have to accept log requests from multiple threads yet write all entries correctly without corrupting the log file.

Answer (score 3):

Closing and opening you file under this scenario will create a race condition like you suspect. You cannot keep the stream open and pass the object to the thread because you might end up with a similar issue if you call from different thread. Your best solution remain using a thread safe method that will write what you send to it.

the methods are static because the lock has to be accessible from all instance of the class.

```
private static ReaderWriterLockSlim readerWriterLockSlim = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public static void AppendToFile(string path, string text) 
{
    // Set to locked (other thread will freeze here until object is unlocked
    readerWriterLockSlim.EnterWriteLock();

    try
    {
        // Write that will append to the file
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            // append the text
            sw.WriteLine(text);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clear the lock
        readerWriterLockSlim.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use a logging library. Or an ActionBlock<T> that queues messages from multiple threads and writes them one by one using a simple writer